# Reactjs check how user arrived on the website

Tags: reactjs, referrer

I was wondering how I can check the referer site that sent a user to my own website. I want to know if it was through a google search, facebook or any other website in order to analyze my traffic (Without google analytics).

Comment: Question is logically correct but don’t understand why people simply downvote without a reason

Comment: Your username kind of explains it, I guess :)

Comment: :) generally I am seeing people simply down-voting questions and answers the next second they are posted without a valid reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it out by `http referer`, just search "http referer" on Google, you can get something.